# Running out of File Descriptors with Connector.open

Tags: java, java-me, network-programming

Here is most of the relevant code, running on a cRIO with the FRC Java image:

```
try {
        SocketConnection http = (SocketConnection) Connector.open("socket://" + BEAGELIP);
        InputStream data = http.openInputStream();
        database = "";
        int p = data.read();
        while (p >= 0) {
            database += (char) p;
            p = data.read();
        }
        data.close();
        http.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

This method is being repeatedly called.

After repeated failures to connect (e.g., the server is not plugged in), the IOException switches from `java.io.IOException: ConnectException: connect refused` to `java.io.IOException: errno: 24 on fd:-1 during socket create`

We think the reason this might be happening is because on failure, `Connector.open` returns null, which we cannot `close()`, freezing up a filedescriptor.

What is the correct way to prevent all of the file descriptors from being used up in this procedure?

If anyone can give a suggestion on how this should be done, that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

Your closes must be in a finally {} block. Otherwise they don't happen if there was an exception, and there will be an exception sooner or later,

Comment: We attempted this, however, Connector.open does not manage to get its return saved to the variable, and so we have only null to close.

If this is the way it needs to be done, indeed, it would be helpful for you to give a more indepth explanation.